# Calculate Nth power of a big matrix with small O(space)

Tags: matrix, computer-science, multiplication

Given a medium/big sized matrix[i][j] (eg. 50k*50k elements), that represents an adjacency matrix for a graph with weighted edges i->j, which is most likely not mirrored, so every element counts. I want to calculate it's Nth power to get its graph walks (yes I'd modulo the elements once they get too big), then I want to sum the columns of the result.

However, even if I only work with the M^1 and the M^i matrices (and that would be perhaps too slow to do N multiplications), 50k^2 is a lot of memory by itself, and that's double the memory.

Is there an algorithm to obtain the sum of columns of the Nth power of a matrix that doesn't require to have the entire matrix loaded? (something like row by row multiplication, although I cant figure how since to get an element you need an entire row and entire column, so that leads to me having the entire matrix loaded). Preferably not having to save and load from disk every single multiplication.

Comment: The memory wouldn't be 50k^2 -- it would be 2500 k^2 = 2.5G. Each of those 2.5 G items would require 50 k multiplications, so just a single full product flirts with infeasibility unless you have a supercomputer. For M^2 you can of course get a row or column without a full compute, but not in a way which generalizes nicely to higher powers. Adjacency matrix approaches for graphs don't scale very well. Whatever it is you are trying to do, think of it more directly as a graph theory problem. Do things like BFS from the nodes instead of matrix power computations

Comment: Also -- you might get a better answer if you migrate it to Math Overflow since it really is more of a math question then a programming question.

Comment: I want to program it though, I dont understand their (mathematicians) funny symbols. I do want to obtain the walks, which means I have to multiply the adjacency matrices, is there another way to obtain a k-length weighted walk of a graph?

Comment: Are you trying to find *all* such walks -- or the shortest one? Some variation of BFS seems the way to go: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search . If you really want all walks you need to compute the power either explicitly or implicitly. You can at least use exponentiation by squaring which will help somewhat.

Comment: I want to sum the columns of the final resulting matrix, so I can reduce the problem to obtain the sum of a single column "i" of the resulting matrix, and do it 50k times for every column, assuming it is possible to obtain that without solving the entire matrix anyway. I'm not feeling doing BFS would help, since that will explode quickly, but I'll give it a look.